# How do I prevent the blue highlight to appear

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a unorderedlist and everytime I doublclick the unorderedlist the textContent of the unorderedlist gets highlighted with a blue color what should I do to prevent it to happen again and please no jquery ust pure vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the `blue highlight` is the user selection!

you can set `user-select:none` for the `li` in css

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

> The user-select CSS property controls whether the user can select text.

```
li {
 user-select: none;
}
```

This however prevents users from being able to select and copy content.

Answer (score 0):

quick google search:

```
::selection {
  background: black; // change color here
}
```

add this to css.

selecting specific elements:

```
ul li::selection {
  background: #fff2a8;
}
```